# Version control for large files without deltas between 2 local folders (not across network)?

Tags: version-control, usb, versioning

Here is what I want to do: I have a USB hard drive where I have data (pictures, audio files, etc). This takes a lot of space, and has many files, which are not text, but binary files.

Often I will reorganize this folder, add files into it, remove some, so the change can come from either comp-A or comp-B, just like I'd do on a personal repository, except that now it takes much more space.

I can't afford using traditional version control across an internet connection, for 2 reasons:

- Too much bandwidth
- I don't want to "delta" the files, because there are small enough (beween 100kB and 20MB) to be replaced instead of "diff'd". A hash of the file is enough to guarantee the file has not changed and doesn't require updating.

I want to do it from my computer to my USB hard drive (and maybe vice versa), so it'd be between two folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks more like an artifact repository than a version control system.
The path of that referential can be one store on your usb key.

An artifact repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) allows you to store your files, with for each one an associated SHA1 and MD5 checksum. See "[What is a repository](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/repoman-sect-repo.html)".

Comment: I'm so proud I got answered by an user with so much reputation. thanks.